# Join three tables and orderBy in laravel getting an error

Tags: php, join, laravel-5

I'm trying to use join() in laravel5.1 but I'm getting this error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 666: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous
>   (SQL: select * from `quizzes` inner join `question_numbers` on
>   `question_numbers`.`quiz_id` = `quizzes`.`id` and
>   `question_numbers`.`question_id` = `multiple_choice`.`id` inner join
>   `multiple_choice` on `multiple_choice`.`id` =
>   `question_numbers`.`question_id` where `id` = 1)

I have three tables here and I want to join these three tables. What I want first is to get a quiz `where` id `=` to a specific id then join the table `question_numbers` where `question_numbers.quiz_id` is `=` to the `quiz.id` then join the table `multiple_choice` `where` `multiple_choice.id` is `=` `question_numbers.question_id` and `where` `question_numbers.question_type` `=` `multiple_choice`.

**What I have:**

```
$quiz = DB::table('quizzes')->where('id', $id)
                ->join('question_numbers', function($join){
                    $join->on('question_numbers.quiz_id', '=', 'quizzes.id')
                        ->on('question_numbers.question_id', '=', 'multiple_choice.id');
                })
                ->join('multiple_choice', 'multiple_choice.id', '=', 'question_numbers.question_id')
                ->get();

        dd($quiz);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set a table `alias`like this `quizzes as t` for your table that belongs the where condition's `id` (I assume you meant **quizzes** table id column here) and then if you refer it inside `where` like  `where('t.id', $id)`, it will not complain about the ambiguous integrity because other table also have `id` column that's why it is showing you the below Query exception,

> Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Try like this,

```
$quiz = DB::table('quizzes as t')->where('t.id', $id)
                ->join('question_numbers', function($join){
                    $join->on('question_numbers.quiz_id', '=', 't.id');
                })
                ->join('multiple_choice', 'multiple_choice.id', '=', 'question_numbers.question_id')
                ->get();

        dd($quiz);
```

Comment: Now, I'm getting this error **QueryException in Connection.php line 666: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'quizzes.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `quizzes` as `q` inner join `question_numbers` on `question_numbers`.`quiz_id` = `quizzes`.`id` and `question_numbers`.`question_id` = `multiple_choice`.`id` inner join `multiple_choice` on `multiple_choice`.`id` = `question_numbers`.`question_id` where `q`.`id` = 1)**

Comment: check my edit. I fixed that `$join->on('question_numbers.quiz_id', '=', 't.id')` and let me know it is working or not?

Comment: Now, I'm getting another and different error: **QueryException in Connection.php line 666: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'multiple_choice.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `quizzes` as `q` inner join `question_numbers` on `question_numbers`.`quiz_id` = `q`.`id` and `question_numbers`.`question_id` = `multiple_choice`.`id` inner join `multiple_choice` on `multiple_choice`.`id` = `question_numbers`.`question_id` where `q`.`id` = 1)**

Comment: This is because you're trying to refer `question_numbers.question_id = multiple_choice.id` before Inner Join it. what is the purpose of `->on('question_numbers.question_id', '=', 'multiple_choice.id');` TWICE

Comment: It's working now. But what I'm worrying for is that these three tables has `created_at` and `updated_at` fields each table. How do I access a specific one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156404/discussion-between-being-sunny-and-jonjie).

Comment: Hi @BeingSunny I added the `->join('true_false as tf', 'tf.id', '=', 'qn.question_id')` at the end of multiple choice but I'm just getting two results instead of 6 results